# How to provide default panels pages via features, but allow overrides?

Tags: 7, panels, features

I'm working on a D7 distribution and I'd like to provide panels pages for some things like node views. I can do this with Features. But I also want the end user of the site to be able to modify the panels pages *without the feature becoming overwritten*.

I basically just want to install some "default" panels and if the user decides to override them, that's fine, I just don't want to revert their overrides the next time we do a features revert on the site.

Comment: will you/admins be making any changes to the panels after the original feature is deployed (as opposed to the end users changes I mean)? iow will you want to push changes to the panels thru same feature in the future?

Comment: We *will* want to push changes to the panel, yes, but we want it to just affect new site installs and sites that haven't overwritten the panels page.

Comment: Gotcha. will you also push the revised feature to the sites where the panels are overwritten?

Comment: Yes, all sites will be part of this same distro. So they will all receive the feature updates. But for sites that modified the panels pages that these features provided, I don't want those features to appear overwritten.

Comment: Check out the [features doc](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/features/modifying-updating-and-reverting-features) last section "locking", you should be able to lock the panels component in your modified site and apply all the rest of the feature's components from your new version.